# When including classes and they have same name functions (no overloading)

Tags: c++, function, call, header-files

I am working on an assignment. The goal of the assignment is to have 4 different sorting algorithms and compare them to determine when one is better than another.  I have decided to create each sorting method as its own class and pass into the class the vector that is to be sorted.

Since each of these classes will be included and have identical parameters (so no overloading), how can I specify which sort function I wish to call? I have tried doing

- insertionsort.sort(insertvec);       //error: insertionsort not declared
- insertionsort::sort(insertvec);      //error: insertionsort not declared
- sort(insertvec);             //works
- insertionsort->sort(insertvec);  //error: insertionsort not declared

All the classes are using namespace std as I do not see how changing the namespace would help. Yes I have a weak working knowledge of namespace.

UPDATE:

Ok, bad choice of terms. I am not using classes. I was thinking of classes as being cpp and h files, which is not accurate. I have not written the sorting algorithms as classes, only as functions written in a cpp but accessed by the header file, which are included and are called.

So how do I tell the compiler that I want the merge.sort() instead of the insertion.sort()?

Comment: Do you really need classes for this?

Comment: No, I wanted to make them into classes in case I needed/wanted to use them again

Comment: but you can use functions again.

Comment: Yes, but I dont want to have a single class with all the sorting methods

Comment: Why would you even need a single class?

Comment: Sounds like you should use a `namespace` instead of a `class`.

Comment: While I agree with @juanchopanza that classes aren't really needed here, we also can't really help you make the class you do have work without some code to figure out what you've done.  Please post a [MCVE].

Comment: Because Im a student and may not know of better methods

Comment: It is easy. Simply don't write any classes if you don't need them (and it looks like you don't.)

Comment: If I do not use classes, then how do I include them in this and other projects?

Comment: Use an interface! Implement the interface in each of your classes and use them by their interface type. No overloading, and its a single method within each of the sorting classes.

Comment: You don't include classes. You include header files. And header files can contain any legal c++ code, not just classes.

Comment: Using classes makes no difference re. including code in projects. Maybe best to read an introductory C++ book.

Comment: @RichardBarker, If you refer to virtual functions and inheritance, that's unnecessary overhead. A templated solution will allow for more optimization venues by the compiler.

Comment: Ok, I have updated my question to address and correct some mistakes I made in writing it down.

Comment: And why can't you just call one function `insertion_sort()` and another `bubble_sort()` and so forth?

Comment: yes by having the functions have different names this no longer becomes an issue, but I have gone this far and would like to try and solve it using this route. It should be something simple that I need to add to the function call, but I cant seem to figure out what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Since your classes all use the same method signature you should use an interface for that method. Then you can easily use the sorting object (that is, your concrete classes) with the interface type and call the method. This is why interfaces exist in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

Ok so before your edit. I came up with this as a way to have them all in different classes. Which from the comments to your question, you can see is pretty wasteful and not a best practice.

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class InsertionSort1
{
    public:
        void sort(vector<int> &theVector)
        {
            //sort implementation 1
        }
};

class InsertionSort2 
{
    public:
        void sort(vector<int> &theVector)
        {
            //sort implementation 2
        }
};

class InsertionSort3
{
    public:
        void sort(vector<int> &theVector)
        {
            //sort implementation 3
        }
};

class InsertionSort4
{
    public:
        void sort(vector<int> &theVector)
        {
            //sort implementation 4
        }
};

int main()
{
    vector<int> vector1 = {/*elements*/};
    vector<int> vector2 = {/*elements*/};
    vector<int> vector3 = {/*elements*/};
    vector<int> vector4 = {/*elements*/};

    InsertionSort1 algorithm1;
    InsertionSort2 algorithm2;
    InsertionSort3 algorithm3;
    InsertionSort4 algorithm4;

    algorithm1.sort(vector1);
    algorithm2.sort(vector2);
    algorithm3.sort(vector3);
    algorithm4.sort(vector4);

    //examine vectors to see differences
}
```

If you can post your code into your question perhaps I can update my answer to better help you.